# delete request after successfully accpet in node js

Tags: node.js

this is script :

```
function accept(id,value){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/accept',
        method:'POST',
        dataType:'JSON',
        data:{id:id,value:value},
        success:function(doc){
            var id=doc._id;
            $.ajax({
            url: "/remove",
            type: "post",
            data: {id:id},
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });






this is index.js:
```

post('/remove', function (req, res, next) {

var id = req.body.id;

var removedata=reqmodel.findByIdAndDelete(id);

removedata.exec(function (err){

```
  if (err) throw err;  
});




















and error is:
```

reqmodel.findByIdAndDelete is not a function**

Comment: Please format your question properly. And what is `reqmodel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var removedata=reqmodel.findByIdAndDelete(id)

replace with

var removedata=reqmodel.findByIdAndRemove(id)